# Activeadmin - activestorage delete edit multiple photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to find a way to delete the images uploaded from activeadmin using activestorage. I managed to show all the images in the show view and the edit of the resource but i can't seem to find the way to delete each image if i want. my model code:

```
  class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :images
  end
```

And the activeadmin resource file:

```
   ActiveAdmin.register Category do

       permit_params :category_name, :description, :photo_cover, images: []

index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :category_name
    column :created_at
    actions
end


show do |t|
    if t.photo_cover.attached? && t.images.attached?
        attributes_table do
          row :category_name
          row :description
          row "images" do |m|
                m.images.each do |img|
                       span do
                           image_tag(img)
                       end
                end
          end
        end
      else
        attributes_table do
          row :category_name
          row :description
        end
      end
  end


form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|
      f.inputs "Basic Info" do
          f.input :category_name
          f.input :description 
      end

      f.inputs do
          f.input :images, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: true }
      end

       if f.object.images.attached?
            f.object.images.each do |img|
                span do
                   image_tag(img)
                 end
             end
        end

      f.actions
      end
 end
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a custom route in ActiveAdmin model as explained [here](https://youtu.be/NJYtzznKrg0?t=659)

```rb
member_action :delete_category_image, method: :delete do
  @pic = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
  @pic.purge_later
  redirect_back(fallback_location: edit_admin_category_path)   
end
```

in `form do`,

```rb
f.object.images.each do |img|
  li class: "some_class" do
    figure do
      img src: rails_representation_path(img.variant(resize_to_fit: [200, 200])), alt: "Photo"
      figcaption img.blog.filename
    end

    a "Delete", src: delete_category_image_admin_category_path(img.id), "data-method": :delete, "data-confirm": "Are you sure?"
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually, it is supposed to be `a "Delete", href: delete...` instead of `a "Delete", src: delete` since it is an *a* tag